# Array indices start from a value not equals 1 in Ada

Tags: arrays, memory-management, ada

I've got an assignment about implementing access function to an array in Ada.
However, declaration of the array was frustrating for me:

```
A: array[1..15, 5..20] of integer;
```

I found a lot of materials on the internet about multidimensional arrays in Ada, however, non of them mentioned memory allocation in this case. Is it just simple mapping of 1..15 to 5..20? Or, program actually skips first 4 elements in each row of the array and keeps memory blank? What if I try to access A[1, 3]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Ada 2012 specification states](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6.html):

> - The possible values for a given index are all the values between the lower and upper bounds, inclusive; this range of values is called the *index range*.
> - The *bounds* of an array are the bounds of its index ranges.
> - The *length* of a dimension of an array is the number of values of the index range of the dimension (zero for a null range).

Regarding memory representation, [the section of the specification concerned with array operations states](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6-2.html) that the length of an array range is defined by its upper-bound minus its lower-bound, plus `1` (which is a restatement of the third bullet point above).

With this knowledge we can answer your questions:

> Is it just simple mapping of 1..15 to 5..20?

There's an implicit mapping of indexes to internal array range locations, but your mapping is incorrect.

With `array[ 1..15, 5..20]`:

- The 1st dimension array range length is `15 - 1 + 1`, so 15 elements long.
- The 2nd dimension array range length is `20 - 5 + 1`, so 16 elements long.

> Or, program actually skips first 4 elements in each row of the array and keeps memory blank?

No, as per the specification the system will not allocate space for array elements not accessible by the defined range.

> What if I try to access A[1, 3]?

The specification states an index bounds check will be performed based on the range the array was initialized with, given that `1,3` is outside the range `[1..15,5..20]` this would result in a runtime index-out-of-bounds error.

Comment: There is no 0th dimension. The first, `A'Length(1) = 15`, the second, `A'Length(2) = 16`

Comment: @egilhh I've corrected my answer, thank you for the feedback.